# Spark - Adding JDBC Driver JAR to Google Dataproc

Tags: apache-spark, jdbc, google-cloud-platform, apache-spark-sql, google-cloud-dataproc

I am trying to write via JDBC:

```
df.write.jdbc("jdbc:postgresql://123.123.123.123:5432/myDatabase", "myTable", props)
```

The [Spark docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.1/configuration.html) explain that the configuration option `spark.driver.extraClassPath` cannot be used to add JDBC Driver JARs if running in client mode (which is the mode Dataproc runs in) since the JVM has already been started.

I tried adding the JAR path in Dataproc's submit command:

```
gcloud beta dataproc jobs submit spark ... 
     --jars file:///home/bryan/org.postgresql.postgresql-9.4-1203-jdbc41.jar
```

I also added the command to load the driver:

```
  Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver")
```

But I still get the error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgresql://123.123.123.123:5432/myDatabase
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From my experience adding `driver` to the properties usually solves the problem:

```
props.put("driver", "org.postgresql.Driver")
db.write.jdbc(url, table, props)
```

Comment: Works great.  Should be added to docs. (note: the code I have in my question has not changed so that may or may not be necessary)

Comment: Funny thing is it is not always necessary but I cannot figure out what exactly makes a difference.

Comment: complexity will do that to any system ;)

Answer (score 2):

You may want to try adding `--driver-class-path` to the very end of your command arguments:

```
gcloud beta dataproc jobs submit spark ... 
    --jars file:///home/bryan/org.postgresql.postgresql-9.4-1203-jdbc41.jar \
    --driver-class-path /home/bryan/org.postgresql.postgresql-9.4-1203-jdbc41.jar
```

Another approach if you're staging the jarfile onto the cluster before the job anyway is to dump the jarfile you need into `/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/` where it should automatically be part of the driver classpath for both Hadoop and Spark jobs.

Comment: Putting the driver-class-path at the end did not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can add jar (from `--jars` argument) to Spark Driver class-path using `--properties` argument when submitting Spark job through Dataproc:

```
$ gcloud dataproc jobs submit spark ... \
    --jars=gs://<BUCKET>/<DIRECTORIES>/<JAR_NAME> \
    --properties=spark.driver.extraClassPath=<JAR_NAME>
```