# Connecting SQLserver jdbc driver to Dataproc cluster

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, google-cloud-dataproc

I am working on PySpark application on analyzing Aviation Data. The Database is a MS SQLServer DB. While connecting to the database on the server. I get an error of "No suitable driver". However when I run on local machine with CLI and add JDBC driver jar file to driver-class-path, it runs and connects with DB. But when I try to run on Dataproc cluster, it throws an error of "No suitable driver".

The code snippet is as follows:

```py
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.dataframe import DataFrame
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

spark = SparkSession.builder
    .appName('Test')
    .getOrCreate()

df = spark.read.format("jdbc").options(
        url="jdbc:sqlserver:XYXYXY",
        database="data1",
        user="YYYY", password="XXXX",
        dbtable="db")
    .load()
```

The Error was:

```java
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o209.load.
: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(DriverManager.java:315)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCOptions$$anonfun$7.apply(JDBCOptions.scala:84)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCOptions$$anonfun$7.apply(JDBCOptions.scala:84)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCOptions.<init>(JDBCOptions.scala:83)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCOptions.<init>(JDBCOptions.scala:34)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcRelationProvider.createRelation(JdbcRelationProvider.scala:34)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:307)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:178)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:146)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Is there other way to add JDBC jar files to the Dataproc cluster?

Comment: If you can't show the code, maybe you can simplify it, change the variable names etc, so it has a similar behaviour but nothing secret any more.

Comment: I have updated my question.

Comment: You can try adding the the jdbc jar under /usr/lib/spark/jars of the master node.

Comment: I tried but it is still showing the same error

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32958311/spark-adding-jdbc-driver-jar-to-google-dataproc/49934170) and [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49934170/3227693) to it that shows how to add JDBC driver to Spark Driver classpath using `gcloud` command:

```
$ gcloud dataproc jobs submit spark ... \
    --jars=gs://<BUCKET>/<DIRECTORIES>/<JAR_NAME> \
    --properties=spark.driver.extraClassPath=<JAR_NAME>
```