# How to call or import a table from Google cloud SQL into Spark dataframe?

Tags: mysql, sql, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, pyspark

I have created an instance in Google Dataproc and I am running pyspark over it.  I am trying to import data from a table into this pyspark. So I  created a table in Google cloud platform SQL. But I don't know how to call or import this table from other pyspark.  Like I dont have any url kind of thing to point to this table. Could you please help in this regard.

Comment: https://cloudacademy.com/course/introduction-to-google-cloud-dataproc/running-a-simple-job-1/

I would go through this to understand how DataProc works with GCP.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you could use `spark.read.jdbc()`: [How to work with MySQL and Apache Spark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27718382/how-to-work-with-mysql-and-apache-spark)

The challenge with Cloud SQL is networking -- figuring out how to connect to the instance. There's two main ways to do this:

1) Install the [Cloud SQL proxy](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/sql-proxy)

You can use [this initialization action](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dataproc-initialization-actions/tree/master/cloud-sql-proxy) to do that for you. Follow the instructions under "without configuring Hive metastore", since you don't need to do that:

```
gcloud dataproc clusters create <CLUSTER_NAME> \
    --scopes sql-admin \
    --initialization-actions gs://dataproc-initialization-actions/cloud-sql-proxy/cloud-sql-proxy.sh \
    --metadata "enable-cloud-sql-hive-metastore=false"
```

The proxy is a local daemon that you can connect to on localhost:3306 and proxies to the cloud sql instance. You'd need to include localhost:3306 in your jdbc connection uri in spark.read.jdbc().

2) If you're instead willing to add to your driver classpath, you can consider installing the [Cloud SQL Socket factory](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-jdbc-socket-factory).

There's some discussion about how to do this here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cloud-dataproc-discuss/Ns6umF_FX9g and here: [Spark - Adding JDBC Driver JAR to Google Dataproc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32958311/spark-adding-jdbc-driver-jar-to-google-dataproc).

It sounds like you can either package it into a shaded application jar in pom.xml, or just provide it at runtime by adding it via `--jars`.